# Cannot find class [org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider] using Second-level cache of Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm following a tutorial using second-level cache of Hibernate. The hibernate version is `hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar`.But when I configure it in `hibernate.cfg.xml` with properties `hibernate.cache.provider_class`. The value should be `org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider` according to the tutorial. But in my case, I can't find this class. I checked the jar file and didn't find this class in it.

Does anyone know where it's placed? Is it changed because of the version?

When I searched this issue online, I found that there's other ways configuring the second-level cache of Hibernate. It will be grateful if you can explain this as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [ehcache site](http://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.10.0/html/ehc-all/index.html#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set/co-hib_about_using_ehcache_with_hibernate.html) you will find documentation about hibernate integration.

For Hibernate 4 use `org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory`

Also check that you have the correct hibernate-ehcache library. If you are using maven, the dependency for H4 is:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>  
   <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Edit: [here](http://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.10.0/html/ehc-all/index.html#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set/co-hib_about_using_ehcache_with_hibernate.html) is a guy that get all the needed libaries directly from *ehcache distribution zip*, maybe is your case.

Comment: Yes, I noticed this. After copied all the jars into my classpath, it still can't find the class EhCacheProvider. So I'm not sure what happened here. Thanks for your answer and I will try it out. As you said, the class I used in my configuration file is available in the previous version of Hibernate?

Comment: I just get confused. I edit the answer, take a look to the added link. Regards